# Java Scanner nextInt problem, need to stop error when entering a string and loop back

Tags: java, loops, exception, java.util.scanner

```
    private static int getNumberOfPlayers() {
    System.out.println("Please enter number of players ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfPlayers = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have selected " + numOfPlayers + " Players");
    // controlling input, at least 2 - at most 4 players can play the game
    while (numOfPlayers < MIN_NUM_PLAYERS || numOfPlayers > MAX_NUM_PLAYERS) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 2 and 4: ");
        numOfPlayers = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have selected " + numOfPlayers + " players");
    }
    return numOfPlayers;
}
```

When the player enters anything other than and int here the game crashes. I would like a sout message to tell the user and loop back so they can try again instead of crashing. Could someone please help me modify this method to implement this functionality. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check to see if there is a next parseable int. (`Scanner::hasNextInt`)

Comment: Could you modify the code for me so I can see it in action?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use exception handeling like this. This might be what you want:

```
 private static int getNumber() {

System.out.println("Please enter number of players ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int numOfPlayers = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("You have selected " + numOfPlayers + " Players");

int  newNumOfPlayers;
// controlling input, at least 2 - at most 4 players can play the game
while(true){

if (numOfPlayers < MIN_NUM_PLAYERS || numOfPlayers > MAX_NUM_PLAYERS) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 2 and 4: ");

    try{
   newNumOfPlayers = sc.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception ex){
         System.out.println("Please select a number only");
         sc.next();
         continue;
    }
    numOfPlayers = newNumOfPlayers;
    System.out.println("You have selected " + numOfPlayers + " players");
    return numOfPlayers;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I feel like youre really close with this but it doesnt work. When you enter a correct number of players 2-4 it just prints "You have selected 2 Players" and hangs.

Also if I enter an incorrect number of player more than two times the game starts. So it only loops through the validation one time.

Comment: The amount of code and description , you had provided says only those things, can you please elaborate what you really want.